Generalisation of five lemma

Consider exact sequence of chain complexes $A\to B\to C\to D\to E$, if $A,B,D,E$ are acyclic, does it follow that $C$ is acyclic?

In the case of short five: $0\to B\to C\to D\to0$, this follows immediately from zigzag lemma.
But in case $A,E\neq 0$ this should be wrong. Do you have a counterexample for this generalization? The original wrong proof I have in mind is using five lemma and consider $ \ker d \to \text{Im} \, d$. Say  $$\begin{array}& A\to &B\to &C\to &D\to &E\\\downarrow{d_A}&\downarrow{d_B}&\downarrow{d_C}&\downarrow{d_D}&\downarrow{d_E} \\ A\to &B\to &C\to &D\to &E\end{array}$$, take kernel and image of $d$ (which are (co)limits), there is a diagram(I'm shaky on commutativity here)
$$\begin{array}& \text{Im} d_{A}\to &\text{Im} d_{B}\to &\text{Im} d_{C}\to &\text{Im} d_{D}\to &\text{Im} d_{E}\\\downarrow{}&\downarrow{}&\downarrow{}&\downarrow{}&\downarrow{} \\\text{ker} d_{A}\to &\text{ker} d_{B}\to &\text{ker} d_{C}\to &\text{ker} d_{D}\to &\text{ker} d_{E}\end{array}$$
I see this argument has a problem that kernel and image is not exact functor so I cannot use five lemma.

Where does the proposition come from? I doubt the correctness.

I don't know if it is correct, and I dont know a counterexample. Do you see any problem in my proof?

I do not see how to induce a long exact sequence from $A \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow C \longrightarrow D \longrightarrow E$. But if we split $A \longrightarrow B \longrightarrow C \longrightarrow D \longrightarrow E$ into short exact sequence, I do not see how to prove this proposition. Can you write your proof in detail?

I see my original argument is wrong, and now I think there is some counterexample

Take $R=\mathbb{Z}/(4)$ and consider the chain complexes $A=B=D=E$ given by :
$$ \cdots \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/(4) \xrightarrow{(\cdot 2)} \mathbb{Z}/(4) \xrightarrow{(\cdot 2)} \mathbb{Z}/(4) \to \cdots $$
Which is acyclic and the complex $C$ given by:
$$ \cdots \to \mathbb{Z}/(4) \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z}/(4) \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z}/(4) \to \cdots $$
Which is clearly not acyclic. Then consider the exact sequence
$$ A \xrightarrow{(\cdot 2)} B \xrightarrow{(\cdot 2)} C \xrightarrow{(\cdot 2)} D \xrightarrow{(\cdot 2)} E $$
If I am not missing something, here you have a counterexample.

Here's a slightly simpler example. There are easy examples of chain maps $D\xrightarrow{\alpha}E$ between acyclic complexes that have a kernel that is not acyclic.
For example, let $D$ be the complex
$$\cdots\to0\to0\to\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\text{id}}\mathbb{Z}\to0\to\cdots$$
of abelian groups, let $E$ be the complex
$$\cdots\to0\to\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\text{id}}\mathbb{Z}\to0\to0\to\cdots$$
obtained by shifting $D$ one place to the left, and let $\alpha$ be the chain map that is the identity map in the middle degree, so that $\ker\alpha$ is the complex
$$\cdots\to0\to0\to0\to\mathbb{Z}\to0\to\cdots,$$
and so there is an exact sequence
$$0\to0\to\ker\alpha\to D\xrightarrow{\alpha}E$$
of complexes where all terms apart from the middle one are acyclic.
